# What's the point of UNI token?

Tags: uniswap

From what I've seen it is totally useless? I was hoping they use it at least for some functioning or something but it seems to me it is just used to enable flow of money to authors of Uniswap.

Answer (score 1):

It is a profit-sharing token, similar to SUSHI, but fee sharing is not enabled yet (likely due to unvoiced regulatory reasons).

Comment: what is fee sharing token

Comment: You get share of profits.

Comment: Clarified, it's a profit sharing token. Basically profits from Uniswap fees.

Comment: aha thanks for info then. but fees (gas) is in ethereum?

Comment: There are trading fees paid to the liquidity providers and the exchange and there are gas fees paid to the miners. Two separate parties are serving you.